# The correct notation of a function that contains an expression with NIntegrate

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerical-integration, function-construction

I tried to set the function `Px[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_]`.  Why does `Px[1.22, 0.44, 1.40, 1.81]` not give out a specific number?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
imax = 1; jmax = 2;
Psi[r_, z_, i_, j_] := Exp[-b[j]*z^2]*Exp[-a[i]*r^2];
(*a[i] and b[i]*)

a[1] = a1;
b[1] = b1;
Do[a[i] = a[i - 1] qa, {i, 2, imax}];
Do[b[j] = b[j - 1] qb, {j, 2, jmax}];

VB[r_,z_]=-(1/(2*Sqrt[r^2+z^2]))*Exp[-Sqrt[r^2+z^2]*1/2];

Px[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Psi[r, z, 1, 2] *VB[r, z]*Psi[r, z, 1, 2]*r, {r, 
   0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]
Px[1.22, 0.44, 1.40, 1.81]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is scoping. The literal symbols for arguments `Pattern[a1 ,_]` etc. do not appear literally in the body of the function. The arguments don't set the values of global variables.  The easiest fix is as follows, though it does not improve the programming style:

```
Px[a10_, b10_, qa0_, qb0_] := 
  Block[{a1 = a10, b1 = b10, qa = qa0, qb = qb0},
   NIntegrate[
    Psi[r, z, 1, 2]*VB[r, z]*Psi[r, z, 1, 2]*r,
    {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]
   ];
```

---

*Update: A better refactoring*

```
Psi[r_, z_, a_, b_] := Exp[-b*z^2]*Exp[-a*r^2];
Px[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] :=
  NIntegrate[
   Psi[r, z, a1, b1 qb]^2*VB[r, z]*r,
   {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you also demonstrate the right programming style for this piece of code

Comment: @MamMam Your code is not easy to understand. I guess I'd start with `Psi[r_, z_, a_, b_] := Exp[-b*z^2]*Exp[-a*r^2];` and pass `a1` for `a_` and `b1 qb` for `b_`. -- oh, another answer just showed. Maybe they refactored the code.

Comment: Oh, they did the same thing I did, except in a different way.

Comment: Yes) but in any case, it would be great if you could also demonstrate the right programming style of this piece of code

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please take a look at my similar but more complicated version of the question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285707/correct-notation-of-a-function-with-a-complicated-structure-of-variables

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind `qa` and `qb` to output of `Px`. Also you have `a[1]` and `b[1]` with no values. This will not work for `NIntegrate`

One way around it is

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
imax=1;jmax=2;
Psi[r_,z_,i_,j_]:=Exp[-b[j]*z^2]*Exp[-a[i]*r^2];
Do[a[i]=a[i-1] qa,{i,2,imax}];
Do[b[j]=b[j-1] qb,{j,2,jmax}];
VB[r_,z_]=-(1/(2*Sqrt[r^2+z^2]))*Exp[-Sqrt[r^2+z^2]*1/2];
Px[a1_,b1_,qaa_,qbb_]:=Module[{tmp},
    tmp=Psi[r,z,1,2]/.{qa->qaa,qb->qbb,a[1]->1,b[1]->2};
    NIntegrate[tmp*VB[r,z]*tmp*r,{r,0,Infinity},{z,-Infinity,Infinity}]
];
Px[1.22,0.44,1.40,1.81]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I just assigned random values for `a[1]` and `b[1]`

You can see the problem if you do

```
Psi[r, z, 1, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is a better way to write all the above if needed without having globals flying all over the place. But the above fixes what you have for now.

Comment: Thanks! It would be great if you could also demonstrate the best way to write the code